# auth.uid is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "userdata":{
        "$id":{

         ".read": "(auth.uid=='aI2OGxb2pnY58ix5ugZLv0rhZqn2')",
         ".write": "(auth.uid=='aI2OGxb2pnY58ix5ugZLv0rhZqn2')"


    }
    }
  }
}
```

Actually my rule is so different. But to confirm that auth.uid is not working for me. I added this into my rules and I got same result (Permission Denied).

And my original uid is also same as given in the above rules.

So are there anything wrong in the rule structure or I'm doing anything wrong in firebase configuaration.

Thanx

Comment: Cross-posted: https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/698664/authuid_not_working_in_firebase_rules/

Comment: Are you trying to read/write at `/userData` or `/userData/$id` when you get permission denied?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to set `read` and `write` rules to `false`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != false",
    ".write": "auth != false",
    "userdata":{
      "$id":{
       ".read": "auth.uid == $id",
       ".write": "auth.uid == $id",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No problem. So if you think that my answer helped you, consider accepting it and giving a +1. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it's adding reading and writing access to each child

Comment: So than, for each child add your own specific type off access. Please take a look at [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). You can use also the `SIMULATOR` if is working or not.

Comment: Look at the rule I provided in the question section

Comment: Change that particular id `aI2OGxb2pnY58ix5ugZLv0rhZqn2` in the rules section with `$id`. But in the SIMULATOR you can use it to verify if it works.

Comment: I know but that's not the problem, that particular uid is my original id which I'm using rn. So added this for testing and it should work because the auth.uid is my original id. But it' s not working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143428/discussion-between-doge-and-alex-mamo).